# How to set Uib Tab more than once through ng-click & ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

So the problem here is that I'm running `ng-repeat` through CSV data, and applying a `ng-click` to each corresponding widget to take the user to a new tab with that data.

It will work for one click and then from there it will register the click, and log to to the console but refuse to take me back to the tab via `ng-click`. Only by clicking the tab headers can I return to said tab.

What makes matters even more peculiar is identical code on another page works absolutely fine.

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm">

<uib-tab index="$index" heading="Overview">

<rd-widget-body style="cursor:pointer;user-select: none;" ng-click="setTab($index)">

<uib-tab index="$index" ng-repeat="x in data | ragFilter" ng-click="setTab($index)" style="user-select: none; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.setTab = function (newTab) {
    $scope.activeForm = newTab;
}
```

It registers the fact that I'm clicking the widgets, it just won't set the tab more than once through the `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that because I held this functionality within an ng-if statement which creates and destroys a unique scope accordingly it wasn't tracking the int value assigned to activeform.

Assigning the int into an object as follows fixed the issue.

```
$scope.setTab = function (newTab) {
    $scope.activeForm = { "i": newTab};

}

uib-tabset active="activeForm.i">
```